# How can I make child_process.spawn return a Promise in my TypeScript module?

Tags: typescript, async-await, child-process, spawn

I'm trying to write a little module that uses `child_process.spawn` to clone a git repo and return a Promise but it fails on me. When I'm using spawnSync it works.

Here is the sync code that works.

```
import {spawnSync} from 'child_process';
export default async function clone(options: { url: string; path: string; }) {
  const url = options.url;
  const target = options.path;
  const args = ['clone', url, target];
  return spawnSync('git', args);
}
```

This is the async code that fails and returns `undefined`

```
import {spawn} from 'child_process';
export default async function clone(options: { url: string; path: string; }) {
  const url = options.url;
  const target = options.path;
  const args = ['clone', url, target];
  const process = spawn('git', args);
  process.on('close', function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      process.addListener('error', reject);
      process.addListener('exit', resolve);
    });
  });
}
```

I also tried:

```
process.on('close', function (code) {
   return code;
  });
```

or

```
process.on('close', function (code) {
   return Promise.resolve(code);
  });
```

and several other things like `…on('exit', function(code){
  return code
})`

Any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're close, you just need to return the promise from your `clone` function (which doesn't need to be `async`, since you need to explicitly create the promise). Also, you're hooking the error event at the wrong time (and via the wrong method as far as I can tell):

```
import {spawn} from 'child_process';
// *** Not async
export default function clone(options: { url: string; path: string; }) {
  // *** Return the promise
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    const url = options.url;
    const target = options.path;
    const args = ['clone', url, target];
    const process = spawn('git', args);
    process.on('close', function (code) { // Should probably be 'exit', not 'close'
      // *** Process completed
      resolve(code);
    });
    process.on('error', function (err) {
      // *** Process creation failed
      reject(err);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: "Also, you're hooking the error event at the wrong time (and via the wrong method as far as I can tell)" soo close :D